# Grant privileges to specific namespaces for every user

Tags: kubernetes

I have bunch of users. Every user should be able to create/change/delete substances in namespaces like `*-stage`. Namespaces can be added or removed dynamically. I can create ServiceAccount in every namespace and grant privileges.

I created pod in k8s and install kubectl and ssh into it. So every user has access to this pod and can use kubectl. I know that I can mount ServiceAccount secrets to pod. As far as I have different ServiceAccounts for every namespace I don't know how to grant privileges to all `*-stage` namespaces for every user. I don't want to create `cluster-admin` ClusterRoleBinding for ServiceAccount, cause users should be able to modify only `*-stage` namespaces. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting a community wiki answer based on OP's solution for better visibility:

> Actually, I have already solved problem. I create `["*"]` role in every
>   `*-stage` namespace and bind it to ServiceAccount. Then I mount ServiceAccount to kubectl pod which is available over ssh. So every
>   user has unlimited access to `*-stage` namespaces.

Also I am adding links for the official docs regarding [ServiceAccount](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) and [role-based access control](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) as a supplement.